# A windows app calls two C++ DLLs with same name and APIs linking to another DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm trying to let my C# app run two different version of C++ DLLs at the same time.

The two DLLs with same file name and APIs are located in different directories:

```
App -> V1/A.dll -> V1/B.dll
    -> V2/A.dll -> V2/B.dll
```

From [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order), I've learned how to make one A.dll call the B.dll in the same directory by [LoadLibraryEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) and [SetDllDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya).

It works fine if my app calls the two version separately:

```
SetDllDirectory("V1");
v1 = LoadLibraryEx("V1/A.dll", null, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
SetDllDirectory(null);
v1.open();
v1.runall();
v1.close();

SetDllDirectory("V2");
v2 = LoadLibraryEx("V2/A.dll", null, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
SetDllDirectory(null);
v2.open();
v2.runall();
v2.close();
```

But it goes wrong (divide-by-zero exception) if the two version run frame-by-frame:

```
SetDllDirectory("V1");
v1 = LoadLibraryEx("V1/A.dll", null, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
SetDllDirectory(null);
SetDllDirectory("V2");
v2 = LoadLibraryEx("V2/A.dll", null, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
SetDllDirectory(null);

v1.open();
v2.open();
foreach (frame in frames)
{
    v1.run(frame);
    v2.run(frame); // divide-by-zero exception occurs
}
v1.close();
v2.close();
```

Since it's likely that v2 calls something wrong in A.dll or B.dll, I added some test APIs in the DLLs:

```
A.dll:
    int _a = 0;
    void set_var(int a, int b) {
        _a = a;
        set_var_b(b);
    }
    void get_var(int *a, int *b) {
        *a = _a;
        *b = get_var_b();
    }

B.dll:
    int _b = 0;
    void set_var_b(int b) {
        _b = b;
    }
    int get_var_b() {
        return _b;
    }
```

It seems that v1 and v2 share the same data memory of global variables in B.dll, but they doesn't in A.dll:

```
int a1, b1;
int a2, b2;
v1.get_var(&a1, &b1); // a1 = 0, b1 = 0
v2.get_var(&a2, &b2); // a2 = 0, b2 = 0
v1.set_var(1, 2);
v2.get_var(&a2, &b2); // a2 = 0, **b2 = 2**
v2.set_var(3, 4);
v1.get_var(&a1, &b2); // a1 = 1, **b1 = 4**
```

My questions:

1. Can an app call two DLLs (A.dll) with same file name and APIs which linking to another DLL (B.dll)?
2. If answer to 1 is yes, is using global variables in B.dll allowed? If it isn't, what is the reason?

Comment: My gut says yes and yes.

Comment: B.dll is an implicit dependency, resolved by the OS loader.  Since it is already loaded after the first load of A.dll, the OS is happy to use it as well to resolve the dependency of the second load.  So you in effect have only *one* copy of B.dll loaded.  Convincing the OS loader that it needs to load V2/B.dll requires a manifest.  Since you seem to be able to modify these dlls, the simple solution is to just give them different names.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant. I knew nothing about manifest and never thought it as a possible solution.

Comment: I also read [How can I specify that my DLL should resolve a DLL dependency from the same directory that the DLL is in?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171011-00/?p=97195) and learn how to solve it by manifest. Since A.dll and B.dll are maintained by other team, renaming the libraries is impractical to my case. Manifest would be a better solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Would you like to post your comment as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s comment.

In my previous case, the two different version of A.dll call the same B.dll:

```
App -> V1/A.dll |-> V1/B.dll
    -> V2/A.dll |   V2/B.dll
```

#### Manifests can be a solution to this:

1. Create manifest file for A.dll project

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
     <file name="B.dll" />
   </assembly>
   ```
2. Add the manifest file into properties of A.dll project: Manifest Tool -> Input and Output -> Additional Manifest Files

##### See Also:

- [How can I specify that my DLL should resolve a DLL dependency from the same directory that the DLL is in?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171011-00/?p=97195)